# FTX API to create order

Tags: python, api

It show error {"success":false,"error":"Missing parameter market"}

```
import time
import hmac
from requests import Request
import requests
import json
api_key=''
api_secret=''
payload = json.dumps({
    "market": 'XRP/USDT',
    "side": 'BUY',
    "price": 0.7,
    "size": 1,
    "type": "limit",
    "reduceOnly": False,
    "ioc": False,
    "postOnly": False,
    "clientId": None
    })
ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
request = Request('POST', 'https://ftx.com/api/orders')
prepared = request.prepare()
signature_payload = f'{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}{payload}'.encode()
print(signature_payload)
signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode(), signature_payload, 'sha256').hexdigest()
prepared.headers['FTX-KEY'] = api_key
prepared.headers['FTX-SIGN'] = signature
prepared.headers['FTX-TS'] = str(ts)
url='https://ftx.com/api/orders'
response = requests.request("POST", url,headers=prepared.headers,data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Can you please recommend how to fix ? I have try many way but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
prepared.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I know this question is a bit older, but maybe someone else needs an answer.
I sent prepared and it worked for me.

```
from requests import Request, Session
import hmac
import json
import time
from pprint import pprint


API_KEY = ""
API_SECRET = ""
SUBACCOUNT = ""


def place_order(market, side, price, size, order_type, reduceOnly, postOnly, ioc=False):
    endpoint = "https://ftx.com/api/orders"

    ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
    s = Session()
    data = json.dumps({
      "market": market,
      "side": side,
      "price": price,
      "type": order_type,
      "size": size,
      "reduceOnly": reduceOnly,
      "ioc": ioc,
      "postOnly": postOnly
    })
    request = Request("POST", endpoint, data=data)
    prepared = request.prepare()
    signature_payload = f"{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}{data}".encode()
    signature = hmac.new(API_SECRET.encode(), signature_payload, "sha256").hexdigest()

    prepared.headers["FTX-KEY"] = API_KEY
    prepared.headers["FTX-SIGN"] = signature
    prepared.headers["FTX-TS"] = str(ts)
    prepared.headers["FTX-SUBACCOUNT"] = SUBACCOUNT

    response = s.send(prepared)
    data = response.json()
    pprint(data)
    return data
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).